# Not able to pass JavaScript variables as params in Hugo static site generator

Tags: javascript, hugo, static-site

I'm using the static site generator hugo. I have a handful of variables I need to pull from a url string and store in localstorage. I then need to access these variables in various locations throughout the site.

In Hugo, I know how to store and access global variables in a global.yml file and I also can pass variables into partials throughout the site. However, in these instances, the variables I am passing in have to be defined as string or numbers. For example, I can access global variables like:

```
{{ .Site.Data.sitewide.global.randomTest }}
```

I can even set strings within a script tag and then pass them in as variables:

```
<script>
{{ .Scratch.Set "greeting" "Hello" }}
</script>
```

However, my issue is that I am not able to pass/interpolate JavaScript variables, such as those from sessionStorage, as params that can be accessed, passed into Hugo partials, or set as global variables.

Is there a way to interpolate JavaScript variables as Hugo variables that can then be accessed throughout the static site?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to think of Hugo not as a framework/library, like jQuery, React, or PHP, etc.

Hugo is only used at build time, not run time. Hugo, at build time, uses its own templates, partials, etc, and variables (regardless of scope) to construct plain old HTML.

Now, you can include any javascript just like you would old-school making a site dynamic on the client -- a great library for that is jQuery as you know. So, you need to think of your javascript in a page, and how you'd use it.

If you look at any Hugo `themes/*theme*/layouts/partials/header` or `./footer` you see javascript being included. That's obviously where you put your code to access the `sessionStorage` and use those vars wherever you want.

If you provide some more detail, we can help give a more specific answer.